# Has any technology from Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D been referenced / used in the wider MCU?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

*Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D* isn't necessarily 'canon' in the MCU.

I was therefore wondering if any technology has referenced / used in the wider MCU in order to link them together.

Two examples (which aren't featured) could be I.C.E.R's and LMD's

Comment: The only one I can think of is that the helicarrier that Coulson was servicing in season 2 was the one used in Age of Ultron.